# How to install and make some small projects by REBLITZ framework in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am newbie with Java (Japanese), and studying at Japanese university.

They are teaching me a framework named REBLITZ.
Here is the link of REBLITZ https://reblitz.jp

I read the document, but still do not know how to install REBLITZ to Eclipse IDE ?
And after install it successfully, how can I make a small project by that framework ?

Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: That website seems to be completely in Japanese, so I think only a Japanese speaker will be able to help you. I suggest that you talk to your instructor. They should have the materials to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to install anything is eclipse is `Help -> Install New Software...`